# Pointers in C not working as expected

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

Ok, this is the important part of the Code. It is only an excerpt.

In steuer.c:

```
static char (*pointer)[8];

extern void test(char *pointer[]); // im not sure, whether this calling is correct

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    check = malloc(sizeof(*pointer) *10);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        test(check[1]);
    ...
}
```

in compute.c:

```
void test(char * compute[])
{
    char temp="test";
    if(strcmp(compute, temp) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is:expected »char **« but argument is of type »char *

Thanks

Comment: The code you've posted has numerous unrelated syntax errors when compiled with GCC. These are due to issues such as the lack of arguments after the symbol 'main'. Can you make sure that you've posted the correct source code?

Comment: The code is only an excerpt. The Point is the correct transfer from the main to the function test.

Comment: the code is only an excerpt, which is fine, but it's one that doesn't compile at all. If you're asking for help with an error, you should provide an exceprt or example that specifically causes that error. For example, I get errors about `check` not being declared. I could add a declaration to my copy, but solving the problem does require actually knowing how you've declared `check`. Similarly, `test(check[]);` is invalid syntax because there is nothing inside the `[]`. Again, without this information, I can't solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, i have update the Code. This is the operation.

Comment: Do note that you've removed the error message from your question now. For anyone trying to answer this, it was `expected »char **« but argument is of type »char *«`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared `test` to take a `char*[]` argument - an array of character pointers, aka an array of strings.

It's clear in both files that you're using this as a character pointer - a `char*` - and therefore should just be a string.

You'll want to change `void test(char * compute[])` to `void test(char *compute)`, so that the types work properly. (You will also want to make the same change in your other declaration.)

Answer (score -1):

sample...

```
static char (* pointer)[8];

void test1(char * pointer){ ; }
void test2(char (* pointer)[8]){ ; }

int main(void){
    char (*check)[8] = malloc(sizeof(*pointer) *10);

    test1(&check[0][0]);
    test2(check);

    return 0;
}
```